# It seems SQL too long in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am a student [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fsvq.jpg)learning both VBA and Access while doing a project, I have the following sql to run to put this info to the LogInfo table in Access. My sql looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO LogInfo ([Date-Time], Description) 
VALUES('2022-04-10 14:50:37', '[AppMsg] 
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShippedDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry, CreditCard) 
SELECT MAX(OrderID)+1, 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvv', 'vvvvvv', 'vvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv' FROM Orders')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts5uP.png)

However, I got the error message like in the screen shot.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I would check your parentheses

Comment: You are passing a string as your last value. The string is encased by single ticks but also contains single ticks. It can't tell those apart.

Comment: How are you constructing this SQL (and how are you submitting/executing)? Is it done in a string variable in VBA? if so, use replace(AppMsg,'''','''''') (4 single quotes, 6 single quotes), instead of AppMsg, to duplicate each single quote before using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that second INSERT sql statement input into Description field, all those apostrophes will be an issue. Use quote marks to define primary string and apostrophes for substrings. Following is syntax for a query object (building in VBA will be a little more complicated).

```
INSERT INTO LogInfo ([Date-Time], Description) 
VALUES("2022-04-10 14:50:37", "[AppMsg] 
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShippedDate, ShipVia, Freight, ShipName, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipRegion, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountry, CreditCard) 
SELECT MAX(OrderID)+1, 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvv', 'vvvvvv', 'vvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv', 'vvvvvvvv' FROM Orders")
```

Assume Date-Time is a text type field.

If you want a dynamic date/time input instead of static string, use Now() function instead - without quote marks.

Advise not to use space nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. Better would be DateTime or Date_Time or LoggedDateTime. Also should avoid reserved words as names. `Description` is a reserved and if it causes issue, enclose in `[ ]` or change field name (not `DESC` as that would definitely cause issue).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys very much for your advice and answer!!!!!

I changed my code (mainly from ' to " in the sql) as following, it worked!

```
sql2 = "INSERT INTO LogInfo " & _
      "([Date-Time], Description) VALUES("""
sql2 = sql2 & msg_date & """, """
sql2 = sql2 & msg_str & """)"
```